# Alternate email addresses for users in Rails - how would I validate uniqueness, or is my method improper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, model

My User model is pretty standard - it has an email:string column and I validate the uniqueness of this in the User model with validates :email, :unique => true.

In order to allow alternate email addresses for users, I created a new model:

**AlternateAddress, with columns user_id:integer and email:string.**

**A User has_many AlternateAddresses, and an AlternateAddress belongs to a User.**
This setup makes for a simple nested form, like this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1.

I realized that I need to validate the 2 email:string columns (one in User.rb, the other in AlternateAddress.rb) "together" - so there are no duplicate email addresses anywhere.

How would I do this? Or, is my entire methodology off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom validator so that it checks the user table and then the alternate addresses table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email_uniqueness # custom
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true

  def email_uniqueness
    if AlternateAddress.find_by_email(self.email)
      self.errors.add(:email, "is already in use by another account")
    end
  end
end
```

You can add something similar to the AlternateAddress field. The method is a custom validator to take care of alternate addresses, but you still want the normal rails validator for uniqueness amongst users.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already storing *some* email addresses in a different model, why not store *all* of them in that different model, and take the `email` field out of your `User` model altogether?

That way, the uniqueness constraints can all be kept in one place (the `AlternateAddress` model). The 'primary' aspect of one email address can then be simply kept as a flag on one of your `AlternateAddress`es for a given `User`.

Comment: It would also be easy to enforce:

User must have *one and only one* `AlternateAddress` with `primary == true`

Comment: Agreed, that's what you should do!

Comment: That's a good idea, but the only thing that makes me hesitate is how I've already set up Authlogic properly using the :email column. I feel like some automatic processes with Authlogic might be in trouble if I do this.

Comment: If you specify your `has_one :primary_email` association before plugging AuthLogic in, it should work…